# Is this MySQL behavior allowed?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, innodb, isolation-level

I setup two JDBC connections to a testing MySQL database and am using InnoDB.
The connections start transactions in different isolation levels and I test which modifications are visible to which connection after which actions:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    final Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
    con1.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
    con1.setAutoCommit(false);

    final Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
    con2.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ);
    con2.setAutoCommit(false);

    System.out.println(countRows(con1));
    System.out.println(countRows(con2));

    addRow(con1);

    System.out.println(countRows(con1));
    System.out.println(countRows(con2));

    con1.commit();

    System.out.println(countRows(con1));
    System.out.println(countRows(con2));

}
```

With these helper methods:

```
public static int countRows(final Connection c) throws Exception {
    final Statement s = c.createStatement();
    final ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test;");
    int count = 0;
    while(rs.next()) {
        count++;
    }
    rs.close();
    s.close();
    return count;
}

public static void addRow(final Connection c) throws Exception {
    final Statement s = c.createStatement();
    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO test (user, age) VALUES ('Guy', 42);");
}
```

I run the code always starting with an empty table. The output I get is

```
0   //initially no rows for both connections
0
1   //con1 adds row
0   //con2 does not see uncommitted new row
1
0   //con1 has committed => Why isn't the new row visible?
```

I would expect the last number to be 1 because `con1` has already committed at this time. Why does this behave like this? Would the behavior I expect be legal with the given isolation levels? As far as I understand, the read phenomenon I'm creating is a phantom read, so this should be fine with `REPEATABLE_READ`, right?

Comment: Try *not* running `countRows(con2)` until after the `addRow(con1)` and see if you get a different result (i.e. the last read of `countRows(con2)` gets a result of `1`

Comment: @Alex In this case `con2` does see the new row inserted by `con1`. But why is my code not creating _phantom reads_ in isolation level `REPEATABLE_READ`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpretation of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read is such that once you have read the data, it will be the same for that transaction for subsequent reads

If you waited to run `countRows(con2)` until after `con1.commit()` then you would see `1` since it hasn't been read yet

I don't think there is any *phenomenon* going on in this scenario, I think this is the exact behavior of `REPEATABLE_READ`.  Once data has been read in a transaction, it is repeatable-ly read the same

Why is it that you think you're seeing an odd phenomenon?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thank you. I was not aware InnoDB uses a stricter definition of `REPEATABLE_READ` than ACID would require. ACID's isolation level `REPEATABLE_READ` allows phantom reads, which occur if two identical queries return different rows within the same transaction. This is what my code does: it inserts a new row so that the first count rows sees `0` rows, and the after the commit (should) see `1` row. But  InnoDB restricts the requirements of `REPEATABLE_READ`, which is the answer to my question. Thank you :)